# Stop urllib.request from raising exceptions on HTTP errors

Tags: python, urllib

Python's `urllib.request.urlopen()` will raise an exception if the HTTP status code of the request is not OK (e.g., 404).

This is because the default opener uses the `HTTPDefaultErrorHandler` class:

> A class which defines a default handler for HTTP error responses; all responses are turned into `HTTPError` exceptions.

Even if you build your own opener, it (un)helpfully includes the `HTTPDefaultErrorHandler` for you implicitly.

If, however, you don't want Python to raise an exception if you get a non-OK response, it's unclear how to disable this behavior.

Comment: you may want to switch to a library that has a different idea of how errors should be handled, like `requests`, no?

Comment: @njzk2 I would prefer to do it with the standard library, but yes I could switch to Requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your own opener with `build_opener()`, the documentation notes, emphasis added,

> Instances of the following classes will be in front of the handlers, **unless the handlers contain them, instances of them or subclasses of them**: ... `HTTPDefaultErrorHandler` ...

Therefore, we need to make our own subclass of `HTTPDefaultErrorHandler` that does not raise an exception and simply passes the response through the pipeline unmodified. Then `build_opener()` will use our error handler instead of the default one.

```py
import urllib.request

class NonRaisingHTTPErrorProcessor(urllib.request.HTTPErrorProcessor):
    http_response = https_response = lambda self, request, response: response

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(NonRaisingHTTPErrorProcessor)
response = opener.open('http://example.com/doesnt-exist')
print(response.status)  # prints 404
```

This answer (including the code sample) was not written by ChatGPT, but it did point out the solution.